# Web job app settings not detected after upgrading to .NET 6.0

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, appsettings

After upgrading a web job to .NET 6.0, it stopped recognizing the app settings and only works if we specify the settings in the `app.config`.

To provide some context, this web job runs every 5 minutes, performs some logic, and then calls an Azure function.

Here's a detailed rundown of what I've done:

I upgraded the project from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 6.0 and updated the dependent packages to their latest versions.

[image]

I noticed that `JobHostConfiguration` is no longer available and that I have to use `HostBuilder` from now on. I adjusted the code accordingly:

[image]

The web job initially started detecting my Azure function, but after deployment, it no longer recognizes the app settings.

Below is a snippet of my Azure function that fails to pick up the app settings:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CDP.Portal.Azure.WJCMTFileUpload
{
    public class Functions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert the customerlists into notes grouped by POS
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static async Task RunFunction()
        {
            TelemetryClient appInsights = new TelemetryClient
            {
                InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppInsights"]
            };

            try
            {

                var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

                if (clientId != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId))
                {

                    //Common.Common.Log("ClientId", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"]);
                    //Common.Common.Log("ResourceUri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceUri"]);
                    //Common.Common.Log("KeyVaultUri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultUri"]);
                    //Common.Common.Log("KeyVaultSecretName", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultSecretName"]);
                    //Common.Common.Log("ResourceApiUri", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceApiUri"]);


                    string token = await CDP.Portal.Azure.Common.Common.AccessTokenGeneratorSecrets(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceUri"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultSecretName"]);



                    //Common.Common.Log("token", token);

                    CrmHelper._client = new HttpClient()
                    {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResourceApiUri"]),
                        DefaultRequestHeaders = { Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token) }
                    };
                }


                List<CustomerList> noteLists;

                string targetFilename = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["targetFilename"];
                string nonoteRow = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["nonoteRow"];

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetFilename))
                {
                    targetFilename = "CMT_";
                }

                try
                {
                    noteLists = await CrmHelper.GetNotesToProcess(appInsights, targetFilename, nonoteRow);

                }
```

The line:

```
var clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
```

seems to return null even though `clientId` is specified in the app settings.

I have already tried different things such as:

- Using `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` instead
- `configSource=` in AppSettings

And here's my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Helpers\CrmHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Helpers\CsvHelper.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\CustomerList.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\Note.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\OdataCollectionWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\Pos.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\TargetList.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Models\Translation.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Helpers\CsvHelper.cs~RF130716c7.TMP" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ClosedXML" Version="0.102.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="110.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Spatial" Version="5.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Edm" Version="5.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.OData" Version="5.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" Version="5.8.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" Version="3.2.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core" Version="3.0.39" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" Version="3.0.39" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" Version="3.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="settings.job">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Helpers\" />
    <Folder Include="Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CDP.Portal.Azure.Common\CDP.Portal.Azure.Common.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please share the code in text format.And also share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Apologies @Harshitha, I've added now the code format.

Comment: Cn you also share the configuration file and your Azure app service configuration settings.

Comment: The issue is with `builder.UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);` line of code.Iam able to retrieve values without setting in config file.Will post an answer in detail.

Answer (score 0):

> recognizing the app settings and only works if we specify the settings in the `app.config`.

- You have set the Environment to Development in `Program.cs` file. Initially even I got the value as null.
- Remove the below line from `Program.cs` file.

```cs
builder.UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
```

***As a workaround, I have used your WebJob Function with my sample code to retrieve config values.***

- In `Functions.cs` file, instead of `ConfigurationManager`, retrieve the values using `IConfiguration`.

***My `Functions.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebJobSQ
{
    public class Functions
    {
        private static IConfiguration myconfig { get; set; }

        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static void RunFunction(ILogger logger)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            myconfig = builder.Build();

           var ClientId = myconfig["ClientId"];

            logger.LogInformation("Sample ClientID - " + ClientId);
        }
    }
}
```

- I don`t have any settings in my local config file.
- Deployed the App to Azure Web Jobs.
- I have set the ClientID in `Environment Variables`.

[image]

***Output:***
[image]

Comment: Add `App.config` or `appsettings.json` file as per your requirement. `.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback.

In the meantime, I tried Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId") and, surprisingly, it worked as expected. I've adapted all my code to it.

I still don't know why, because I know they're both supposed to do the same thing.

Comment: Did you try the sol which I have posted?